# How to create a custom facebook like button?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty, prestashop

I need to create facebook like button in product list page in prestashop. I created the face book like button in below .

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-width="78"  data-height="32" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>

But I need to create facebook like using  <a> tag.
```

How to create facebook like button in custom button. Please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Doesn't it worked


<a class="fb-like" data-href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-width="78"  data-height="32" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false">fb</a>
```

Comment: Its worked. But i need to create     <a class="fb-like" data-href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" data-width="78"  data-height="32" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"><img src="../img/fblike.png" /></a>